# How to use Medical Spell Checker in my tynimce edit?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, tinymce

I am using tinymce editor in my asp.net application, I want to implement the Medical Spell Checker in my tynimce edit, How to do that?

I am using following script for showing spell checked its working fine when i am clicking on spell check option of editor but I want medical spell checker when user write something in text field it must show the error.

```
 tinyMCE.init(
            {
                mode : "exact", elements :  controlID, theme : "advanced",
                plugins : "table,advlink,preview,media,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,spellchecker",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
                external_link_list_url : "example_link_list.js",
                external_image_list_url : "example_image_list.js",
                media_external_list_url : "example_media_list.js",
                paste_use_dialog : false,
                paste_create_paragraphs: false,
                theme_special_link_targets : "_something=My somthing;_something2=My somthing2;_something3=My somthing3;",
                paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
                paste_convert_headers_to_strong : false,
                paste_strip_class_attributes : "all",
                paste_remove_spans : false,
                paste_remove_styles : false,    
                forced_root_block : '',
//              plugin_preview_pageurl : "../Content/PreviewRichTextElement.aspx",
                theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,bullist,numlist,outdent,indent,|,link,unlink,|,image,preview,fullscreen,|,cleanup,removeformat,spellchecker",
                theme_advanced_buttons2 : "formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,forecolor,backcolor",
                theme_advanced_buttons3 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,tablecontrols,|,visualaid",
                spellchecker_languages : "+English=en",
                spellchecker_rpc_url:"../Admin/SpellChecker.ashx"
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look for some more info here: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:spellchecker

Comment: I am already using this, but for the few medical terms its not working thats the reason i need medical spell checker

Comment: i assume the browser used is not firefox only?